# Different ways of building a list of objects

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I have a class called `Fruit` as follows:

```
public class Fruit
{
    public int FruitId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

My intention is to build a `List<Fruit>`, which I am able to achieve using the following code:

```
List<Fruit> fruits = new List<Fruit>();
Fruit a = new Fruit();
a.FruitId = 1;
a.Description = "Apple";
fruits.Add(a);
Fruit b = new Fruit();
b.FruitId = 2;
b.Description = "Ananas";
fruits.Add(b);
```

I am using .net 4.0.
Please let me know, what are the different ways of building a list?

Comment: Are you going to be manually creating your `Fruit` objects? Or could this be done in a loop?

Comment: Also, if you always know the FruitId and Description at the time of instantiation, you might consider placing those in the constructor as parameters. Otherwise, you're just duplicating functionality across several lines of code, unless you instantiate in a loop as ledbutter suggested.

Comment: I am doing it manually...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Collection Initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx). Its more readable IMO.

```
List<Fruit> fruits = new List<Fruit>
{
    new Fruit()
    {
        FruitId = 1,
        Description = "Apple"
    },
    new Fruit()
    {
        FruitId = 1,
        Description = "Ananas"

    }
};
```

For your current code if you are not going to use your object `a` and `b` later in your code and you are only using them to fill your list, then its better that you use collection initializer.

Comment: -1 Your answer does not provide enough information. It's just a link.

Comment: @HighCore, just edited with a code sample

Comment: You don't need the `()` when creating the `Fruit` objects

Comment: @HighCore not very nice to downvote and provide competing answer which is essentially the same.

Comment: @Andrey except mine includes sample code. I also removed the downvote here because of the sample code included.

Comment: @HighCore it is not a big deal to add code, and that is what Habib did in a few seconds answer.

Comment: @Andrey still an answer of just a link is worth a downvote.

Comment: @HighCore it is of course up to you, but I disagree. The answer is on topic, useful and correct, but could be better. I only downvote answers that are misleading or completely off topic and official help agrees with me (or I with it): voting down a post signals the opposite: that the post contains wrong information, is poorly researched, or fails to communicate information. http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

Answer (score 2):

Your code can be rewritten using the [Collection Initializer Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx), like this:

```
var fruits = new List<Fruit> {
                                new Fruit { FruitId = 1, Description = "Apple"},
                                new Fruit { FruidId = 2, Description = "Ananas"}
                             };
```

Also notice the usage of the [var Keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383973.aspx) to avoid repetition.

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest solution is probably to write a constructor for your `Fruit` class:

```
public class Fruit {
    ...
    public Fruit(int id, string desc){
        this.FruitId = id;
        this.Description = desc;
    }
}
```

and now initialize the list with it:

```
List<Fruit> fruits = new List<Fruit> {
    new Fruit(1, "Apple"), new Fruit(2, "Ananas")
}
```

The downside is that you have to write the constructor (good practice anyway, since your properties are public), and the upside is that the initialization of the list is much clearer now because you don't have to write `FruitId` and `Description` all the time!

Answer (score 0):

I would use an initilizer on the collection:

```
List<Fruit> fruits = new List<Fruit>
{
     new Fruit(){ FruitId = 1, Description = "Apple" },
     new Fruit(){ FruitId = 2, Description = "Ananas" },                
};
```